# App crashes in emulator after implementing admob

Tags: android-studio, admob, godot

I´ve build a game with godot 3.5, exported it to android and tested it in the emulator on android studio, but after adding the admob plugin 6.2.0 from Github [ADMobPlugin](https://github.com/Shin-NiL/Godot-Android-Admob-Plugin/releases) the game crashes by default.

[SCREENSHOT OF PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLFAu.jpg)

Tell me if you need information about anything.
I think the problem could be the admob plugin version, but I not sure.
I´m having that problem now for weeks, so please help me.